# Entry Level Java Help: Creating an empty box with an 'x' inside using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm in a high school intro to java course and unfortunately I have a teacher that doesn't really know what he is doing. He understands Java quite well, but completely lacks the ability to teach expecting all the students to be at an advanced level. Our homework tonight is to use arrays to make a box based on the users input to create a empty box with an 'X' in the center. Currently all I have is a filled box and am completely lost on what to do.

Any help what so ever is appreciated :)

EDIT: Added below what the assignment expects it to look like

```
    * * * * * * *
    *           *
    *   *   *   *
    *     *     *
    *   *   *   *
    *           *
    * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show what code you've written so far, and what it is doing versus what you want it to do.

Comment: You should show what you have tried, ideas you have on the theory of how it might work and anything you have started. People wont just do you homework for you. How do you imagine the logic will work?

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis - sorry If I didn't make this clear but I have no clue on what to do, as he has taught us nothing about arrays, coupled with me missing a few days of class due to sickness, I just need some help on where to start

Comment: We can't tell you where to start since your question is quite undetailed and it's unclear what you want

Comment: Do you have a picture/link to your assignment?

Comment: Well here is a start to learn about arrays in java. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm

Comment: @Ivaro18 actually a adding a copy of the task to the question would be preferable to an image or a link. Just as usual, links tend to expire at some time and are a bit of a security-risk. There's an article in the help-center on that topic.

Comment: @Ivaro18 I added in what it is expected to look like, sorry about that

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis Going to start reading thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] array = {
        "* * * * * * *",
        "*           *",
        "*   *   *   *",
        "*     *     *",
        "*   *   *   *",
        "*           *",
        "* * * * * * *"};
        for(String s : array){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Seems to be what you're looking for. Not certain because you're talking about user input, but this will print a box with an X in it, in the console.

Comment: Quite clean :) There *is* an array, and it *is* producing the right output. I love it and upvoted :) On the other hand, probably the original assigment could be more complicated.